# Searching CRUD .json in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0, crud, cakedc

I'm using the CRUD component to format my data to .json  I now need to search my tables and fields. Installed the Cake DC search component, but can't figure out how to get the 2 to work together.  Can someone point me in the right direction?